# I can't change my caption in my region language in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I try to change my caption in my region language but it does not work. I already changed my font to support my region font and it still not works. The message it showed me "??????" when I wrote my region language. 
Here's [a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jekia.jpg).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include all the necessary information in the post itself, including any relevant code. See [ask] and [mcve] for ideas. Cheers!

Comment: Note that the VBE is very en-US centric and only supports ANSI encoding; designer & properties toolwindow might not be able to display Unicode correctly; it's possible the properties can be assigned to a Unicode string at run-time though. Have you tried setting the captions programmatically?

Comment: Can you also mention what language/region you're trying to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following steps:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Click Region
3. Click the Administrative tab
4. Click the Change system locale button
5. Select which language to use when displaying text in programs, such as VBE, that do not support Unicode. The setting will affect all user accounts on your computer.

This should give the desired output.